# Django static files does not load while in the root directory

Tags: python, django

I stored my static files in project root directory but I can't make them load on the browser.

- *configurations*

1. settings.py

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')  

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

2. template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{temp}}</h1>
        <h2><a href="#">Click here</a> to veiw user details</h2>
        <img src="{% static "user/images/smile.png"%}" alt="oh oh didn't show"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Euh, the `STATIC_DIR` is here `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), which is likely *not* the root dir.

Comment: Try using single quotes around `"user/images/smile.png"` like `'user/images/smile.png'`

Comment: like already told by the above comment use different comment's cause they arepart of the img tag they don't have any value unless they are included inside by the above code they are not included so change that to `<img src="{% static 'user/images/smile.png'%}" alt="oh oh didn't show"/>`

Comment: tried but didn't work

Comment: I added the static dir in the app dir then it works fine. Now i wonder why

Comment: My templates folder is also in the root dir and in settings.py ```TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')```  and the templates are loading just fine but problem is with static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `urls.py` add the static url.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```